# sqlite3 python data base setting two unique values

Tags: python, database, sqlite, unique

i use sqlit3 with python i wanna add two unique values to be checked
expected output:

```
Date_1 Name_1 OK
Date_1 Name_1 NO
Date_2 Name_1 OK
Date_1 Name_2 OK
```

i just wanna prevent duplication and check these two constrains at the same time.

i tried:

```
cur.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (
            'Date' BLOB,
            'Name' TEXT,
            'iD' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

            CONSTRAINT Name_Date UNIQUE( Name, Date ) ) """ )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make Name and date your primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ethan, it worked

Comment: You’re welcome. If you still need an internet alias SQLite automatically creates an auto increment column called “index” that you can reference

Comment: That table definition will do what you want.